# error with own struct in c

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

defined in 'commando.h'

```
typedef struct {
    int pid;        /* Prozess ID */
    char* name;     /* Prozess Name (Programm) */
    char* status;   /* Status des Programms */
    int check;      /* bereits abgerufen? 1 - abgerufen, 0 - nicht abgerufen */
} Pstatus;

Pstatus erzeugeProzess (int neuID, char* neuName, char* neuStatus);
```

---

used in 'commando.c'

```
Pstatus erzeugeProzess (int neuID, char* neuName, char* neuStatus){
    Pstatus erzeuge = reserviere(sizeof(struct Pstatus));

    erzeuge->pid = neuID;
    erzeuge->name = neuName;
    erzeuge->status = neuStatus;
    erzeuge->check = 0; 

    return erzeuge;
}
```

while compiling the compiler says: it's an invalid usage of an uncompleted type
and an invalid argumenttype for the erzeuge->pid ... erzeuge->check
don't know whats the Problem

anybody who can explain what I've done wrong?

Comment: in `erzeugeProzess` you declare `erzeuge` as a `Pstatus` struct but then use `->` to access its members which is used for pointers. You should just use `erzeuge.pid` notation

Answer (score 0):

```
first, the definition of the struct as you defined it is deprecated. 
Especially using the keyword 'typedef' 
which is effectively unavailable in C++, (amongst other reasons).
A much better definition of the struct is:

struct Pstatus 
{
    int pid;        /* Prozess ID */
    char* name;     /* Prozess Name (Programm) */
    char* status;   /* Status des Programms */
    int check;      /* bereits abgerufen? 1 - abgerufen, 0 - nicht abgerufen */
};

then your code must reference the struct as 'struct Pstatus'.

then your code would be:
The prototype:

struct Pstatus* erzeugeProzess (int neuID, char* neuName, char* neuStatus);

The declaration:

struct Pstatus* erzeugeProzess (int neuID, char* neuName, char* neuStatus)
{
    Pstatus* erzeuge = reserviere(sizeof(struct Pstatus));

    if( NULL != erzeuge )
    {

        erzeuge->pid = neuID;
        erzeuge->name = neuName;
        erzeuge->status = neuStatus;
        erzeuge->check = 0; 
    }
    else
    {
        perror( "reserviere, %s", strerror(errno) );
    }
    return( erzeuge );
}

Regarding an earlier comment.
Although the stack parameters go away, by that time, the pointer to the reserved area 
is already passed back to the caller.   


By using a pointer in the function prototype and declaration, only a pointer
needs to be passed back, not the whole structure memory.
Also, be sure the caller checks for a NULL return value.
Also, be sure the caller performs something like free(...) to avoid a memory leak
```

Comment: The question is about C, not C++!

Answer (score -2):

A couple of things. One: you are allocating space for a pointer even though you are not declaring one. You want to use `Pstatus *erzeuge` instead. Second, you have already `typedef`ed your struct; you no longer need to use `struct Pstatus` to refer to it. You want `sizeof(Pstatus)`. In short, change your first line to:

```
Pstatus *erzeuge = malloc(sizeof(Pstatus));
```

and your code will work. Here is an ideone example as well: http://ideone.com/kHiyBg

Also, you are return statement should read:

```
return *erzeuge;
```

The alternative is to forgo pointers altogether (which it looks like is what you should be doing anyways):

```
Pstatus erzeuge;

erzeuge.pid = neuID;
erzeuge.name = ...;
```

Comment: Your 1st proposal introduces a memory leak. The referene to what had been allocated to `erzeuge` is lost after having returned from the function.